# Are french fries considered shalem?

Tags: blessing, food, vegetables

For the purposes of priority in making a blessing, is a french fri considered a shalem food or is it considered a broken piece of potato?

Comment: Since it has a name, i would think it's shalem.

Comment: That sounds like an answer.

Comment: Is bread considered Shalem or a broken up piece of wheat?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't know if that is a direct analogy, unless you are making a shehakol on your french fries.

Comment: What difference would it make?

Answer (score 2):

The reason "Daver Shalem" gets priority can be for one of two reasons

1) The food item was created that way ("ברייה") an example could be a apple or even a grape.

2) That by taking the "Daver Shalem" before the other item you are beautifying the mitzvah of making a bracha (Hidur Mitzvah) Thus if you had a large slice of bread and a small roll you would make the bracha on the roll since that has an advantage of being "shalem" (Think of  a formal meal like a wedding. Normally a roll is put in front of each person not several slices of bread since the roll is more esteemed ("mechubidik"*??) )

Since a french fry on its own while technically "shalem" was a) not created that way b) a single french fry is not considered more esteemed to serve over a piece of potato I would say that it does not take any preference over the broken potato based on shalem**.

* mechubidik - apologies for the "yeshivish" but a good translation escapes me at the moment. MY editors please suggest an appropriate translation.

** there may be a case to say that in this case you would go for the bigger of the 2 items but I haven't seen that specifically brought down.

Sources:

Yerushalmi Perek 6 Halacha Aleph

SA 168:1 + Mishna Berurah

[Laws of Brachos Rabbi Forst](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=P_2QlQkNL8sC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: mechubidik = esteemed

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick that you can do on Yom Tov whereby you can take a broken piece of matzah, and burn the broken edge, rendering the piece whole for the purpose of lechem mishna.

Since the fry is surrounded on all sides by crust, I would say that it would be whole just like the formerly broken matzah.

Comment: Can you bring a source for this ? I have heard of it but in recent years I have heard from dayanim that it in fact does not help.

Comment: It is mentioned here but I don't know the primary source.
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1108296/jewish/Lechem-Mishneh-The-Two-Shabbat-Loaves.htm

Comment: Thanks but even there the source, Avraham Hirch, is one person and not any source in the poskim.